# API responds with nothing when called from a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My issue is that I'm trying to call this API from a chrome extension:
https://wss2.cex.uk.webuy.io/v3/boxes?q=8717418549541&firstRecord=1&count=10&sortBy=relevance

Here is the code for calling the API, taken directly from Postman:

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://wss2.cex.uk.webuy.io/v3/boxes?q=8717418549527&firstRecord=1&count=10&sortBy=relevance",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.17.1",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Postman-Token": "32322856-4e8d-4d54-87b2-199bd6181243,bea1c3bd-b5ae-4343-870d-dd73e5c88f95",
        "Host": "wss2.cex.uk.webuy.io",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Cookie": "__cfduid=dc54a227217ab713ddd4423d047c67b5f1568818173",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Using the above code has worked perfectly fine for a long time now. However, since last Thursday, the API stopped giving any response whatsoever. Now the status code says 200 OK but the response tab says "This request has no response data available". Trying to log out the response gives nothing as well.

If you were to simply click on the above API link, the JSON should get shown since there is no authorization. My extension properly sends the API call and I can see the call being sent in the network tab of Developer tools.

Calling the API from Postman, etc... works fine.

Of course, all necessary permissions are set in the manifest and everything was working well until it just suddenly stopped. No errors or warnings, nothing.

Has this happened to anyone before? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [How to avoid Cross-Origin Read Blocking(CORB) in a chrome web extension](//stackoverflow.com/q/54786635)

Comment: @wOxxOm There are no CORB errors of any kind. The request is not blocked and returns with 200 OK. There just is no content...

Comment: It can be silently blocked for the same reason in modern Chrome, AFAIK. The important thing is that content scripts can't make cross-origin requests anymore.

Comment: @wOxxOm Strangely, once I published my Chrome extension my client claimed all to be working just fine. I however still don't see anything from my end. Perhaps I need to use a VPN from my end...